# Rails 4 w/ Heroku RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sunspot-solr, rsolr

my setup: Rails 4, Heroku with Websolr addon.

The Solr search was been working just fine for months with my Rails 4 (production) application. Then one day it quit and I went through the following stackoverflow answers and none of them worked.

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304160/rails-4-rsolrerrorhttp-rsolrerrorhttp-404-not-found), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759906/rails-app-solr-throwing-rsolrerrorhttp-404-not-found-when-executing-searc), [Answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657351/rake-sunspotreindex-rake-aborted-rsolrerrorhttp-404-not-found)

Since I didn't have java installed at one point, they were pretty tedious to go through, but I do need to mention before I answer this that I went through all three answers BEFORE I solved it, so something I did above may have enabled it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a full day of sifting through answers and I was just about to gut my application and remove solr altogether.

I solved it by going to my Heroku dashboard, clicking the Websolr addon icon which took me to the Websolr page for my heroku app. I deleted the index that was there by default and set up a new one with a new name.

Once the new index has been created, copy and paste the text in the field labeled **Configure your Heroku Application**

Lastly, I went to the terminal and entered these commands.

$ heroku config:add WEBSOLR_URL=[url_goes_here]

$ heroku restart

Everything works fine now.

Comment: Looked at tens of answers and help docs, none of which worked… until this one. Thank you!