# Solr won't start reindexing -- Not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

I've tried different approaches to get solr to work, in particular, these [rake sunspot:reindex rake aborted! RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657351/rake-sunspotreindex-rake-aborted-rsolrerrorhttp-404-not-found), but I've ended up with this yet:

```
 $ bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
=> Solr server started

rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error:     Not Found

URI: http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/default/update?wt=ruby
Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}
Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:ActsAsTaggableOn\\:\\:Tag</query></delete>"
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Is solr definitely running?

Comment: Does the URL actually work outside of Ruby? Does Solr answer on that URL? Is the Solr server running on the same machine?

Comment: @MatsLindh, "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr" does.

Comment: Okay, does the index exist then? The reindex task is likely to fail if the index isn't there

Comment: @AlexLynham, http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/default doesn't exist, how to create it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the index. [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Introduction+to+Solr+Indexing) are the docs on indexing and how to create your index. [Here](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html)'s a much quicker but less thorough introduction.

As you're using sunspot, you probably want to [read their docs first](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot). Essentially you need to add a searchable block to your objects to index. After you've added that block, the objects will index on next save, or you can call the rake task you mentioned above.

Here's the example they give for a `Post` object:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :body
    text :comments do
      comments.map { |comment| comment.body }
    end

    boolean :featured
    integer :blog_id
    integer :author_id
    integer :category_ids, :multiple => true
    double  :average_rating
    time    :published_at
    time    :expired_at

    string  :sort_title do
      title.downcase.gsub(/^(an?|the)/, '')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the 2nd links describes how to do that with a "jar" file. but how can I use it? I'm on Rails, not in java.

Comment: I've added "searchable" to my model, the goal now is to start solr and set it up.